# Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName

Tags: hostname, apache-httpd

When i start apache service in my debian 7.8 with the command :

```
root@debian:/home/debian# service apache2  start

[....] Starting web server: apache2apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName
```

. ok

```
In my /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost    
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts   
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback   
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes  
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

In my /etc/hostname

```
localhost
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/apache2/conf.d/httpd.conf`, add the line:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Comment: No such file or directory  in my debian7.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Just create it.